# What can be the reason I can't connect to VPN from different network?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, vpn

I try to connect to a VPN. Before I moved I had no problem establishing the connection but with a new router the old settings don't work anymore. My guess is that I need to forward a couple of ports that the routers firewall might be blocking. But this is just a wild guess. It is a L2TP VPN, by the way. Can someone help me out here?

These are my current router settings.

```
VPN UDP 4500    4500    UDP 4500    4500    
VPN UDP 500     500     UDP 500     500 
VPN TCP 1701    1701    TCP 1701    1701
```

Answer (score 0):

The ports you have forwarded looks to be correct.

```
UDP 500, UDP 4500, UDP 1701
```

In addition to that, you might need to enable the "VPN Passthrough" feature on your router.

The configuration steps depend on the kind of router you are using, here are some examples:

D-Link: http://support.dlink.com/emulators/wbr2310/adv_dmz.htm

Linksys: http://kb.linksys.com/Linksys/GetArticle.aspx?docid=a1814198178c4e2d87b9b1765efcee72_Setting_Up_a_VPN_Passthrough_on_an_E_Series_Wireless_N_Route.xml

Comment: I use a Davolink 2020 router. I can't find any information on how to configure the VPN passthrough..

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with that. I have no experience with that particular router.